# How can I hide the secondary thumbnails when a product variation is selected?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce and I want to remove/hide the secondary thumbnails shown on the product page.

Before selecting a variation you can see two images in the product gallery. The problem is after I select a variation.

The main image changes but the second one doesn't go away. I need to find a way to hide the secondary image/thumbnail.

Please help :(

Comment: Please consider adding screenshots in order to make your question easier to understand.

Comment: Hi, I tried to insert images but since it's my first question, stack overflow didn't let me

Comment: I have the same problem